# Issue finding elements on Barclaycard Samrt Pay hosted payment page using Selenium via Perl

Tags: perl, selenium, payment-gateway

I am trying to create a Selenium test script, in Perl (using [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver)) to test the checkout process of my application.  I have recorded it with the Selenium IDE, and exported it with the Perl webdriver format plugin.  The bits on my site work fine, but when I come to the Barclaycard HPP, it cannot find the elements.  I have tried all applicable variations of find_element and find_element_by... and it does not work.

```
$driver->find_element_by_id("card.cardNumber")->clear;
$driver->find_element_by_name("card.cardNumber")->clear;
$driver->find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="card.cardNumber"]');
$driver->find_element_by_xpath('//*[@onkeypress="return blockNonNumberEvents(event)"]');
```

The only difference I can see, is that the ID adn name tags both contain dots (i.e. id=card.cardnumber)

```
<input type="text" class="inputField" id="card.cardNumber" onkeypress="return blockNonNumberEvents(event)" onkeyup="card_validateCcNumber(event, 'card', card_types, card_logos, card_subVariantExtras, card_subVariantExtrasPhrase)" onchange="card_validateCcNumber(event, 'card', card_types, card_logos, card_subVariantExtras, card_subVariantExtrasPhrase) ; card_doCCCheck('card')" name="card.cardNumber" value="" size="24" maxlength="23">
```

I have verified that the tag values for ID and NAME are unique on the page, tried searching by xpath for the other tags.  The only difference I can see is the dot in the NAME and ID fields.

I know this is a very specific issue, but I am hoping someone else has hit it too, and found a fix/fudge!

Comment: Please show the variations you have tried.

Comment: '$driver->find_element_by_id("card.cardNumber")->clear'       
'$driver->find_element_by_name("card.cardNumber")->clear'     
'$driver->find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="card.cardNumber"]')'     
'$driver->find_element_by_xpath('//*[@onkeypress="return blockNonNumberEvents(event)"]')'

Comment: You realize that that's a different `id` then the HTML in your question has, right? Please [edit] the question and show real code and real HTML, or no-one will be able to help.

Comment: Just hit enter by mistake when typing, it was just another example on the same page of html, but now edited in comment to refelct question

Comment: Please [edit] it in the question. I had already added the first part of the comment.

Comment: Sorry typed when tired and frustrated. Done :)

Comment: I'd be interested to see what your log file says when it cannot find the element. Can you share this information by adding it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the enclosing of card.cardNumber in quotes. When you do this, you are telling perl to concatate card and cardNumber so you end up with cardcardNumber.

If, on the other hand, you use single quotes as in: `'card.cardNumber'` perl will take what is in between the single quotes literally. Thus giving you the desired ending string "card.cardNumber".